# Strip filenames from Swift binary

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, reverse-engineering

Even when applying the highest level of stripping to my Swift binary, I can still see that the compiler embeds filenames as strings into the app binary, which I can then view using [Hopper](https://www.hopperapp.com/).

I'm not necessarily convinced that anyone could do anything particularly nefarious with this information, but equally I'd rather strip the filenames from the binary if I possibly can to make reverse-engineering as difficult as possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you confirmed, that your binary is unmodified after downloading from the AppStore - i.e. that it is not encrypted or obfuscated? If it is encrypted, does it give you enough security as it prevents static analysis of your code? Or do you need stronger measurements in order to prevent a dynamic analysis which requires a jail broken device, special tools and knowledge and dedicated effort?

Comment: In my case it's a binary framework, but I expect it would be the same with an app binary

Comment: Which filenames exactly you have in mind?